# Private Constructor Error C++

Tags: c++, xcode3.2

I'm trying to write a class using the Singleton pattern in C++ for the first time and I get an error simply by making my constructor private, I'm using xcode 3.2 and compiling with gcc 4.2:

```
class GameDirector {

private:
  //Singleton instance
  static GameDirector* director;

  //Constructor
  GameDirector(); //THIS LINE GIVES ME THE ERROR

public:
  //Singleton pattern
  static GameDirector* sharedDirector();
};
```

It gives me 2 errors:

```
error: 'GameDirector::GameDirector()' is private
error: within this context
```

I can't understand why its giving me an error, I thought you were allowed to make constructors private in C++...

Comment: Yes, you're allowed to make constructors private. However, you're almost certainly trying to instantiate `GameDirector` outside the class itself, which obviously won't work with a private constructor. Take another look at the line numbers in the error messages to see where the actual error is.

Comment: Yep, it compiles as is: http://ideone.com/1ckQO Make sure that you are not trying to call constructor somewhere else.

Comment: @Tomalak, unusual comment, what do you mean by localised?  I would have thought of SO very much as a mutual support site where programmers support each other.  Many questions relate to very real problems encountered by programmers at work that have very specific / narrow contexts.

Comment: @Shane: Unusual? I think that you have misunderstood [what SO is for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105365/stack-overflow-has-too-many-low-quality-new-questions). And one of the closevote options is "too localised" so it's quite explicit that we don't deal with that sort of stuff. SO is a site for interesting questions about programming languages, _not_ a "help me fix my code" forum or message board.

Comment: @Tomalak, seems by too localised you appear to mean below acceptable quality, which are hardly the same thing. (Obviously a meta debate so I'll leave it at that).

Comment: @Shane: No, that is not what I mean at all. Too localised is too localised; quality and "topic" are orthogonal. In fact, this is a very well-formed question. (Jeff changed my meta question title to read "low quality"; ultimately, that question is about _both_ issues, so I let it go.) BTW I'm well aware that many questions on SO are very localised: me and other regular SO users are doing our best to get those closed.

Comment: @Tomalak, change the word GameDirector to MyClass, and add a couple of lines showing the attempted instantiation, and the question is pretty generic.  Yes, it's a beginners question, but I'd guess that much of the SO audience are beginners, and who is to say some wouldn't have similar questions and find value in the answers below.  As for quality being orthogonal to anything, I've yet to see a broadly accepted definition of the term.  Personally, I go with Weinberg's  “Quality is value to some person” YMMV.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3449/discussion-between-shane-maclaughlin-and-tomalak-geretkal)

Comment: @Shane: But those lines showing the attempted instantiation _aren't there_. This is a request for debugging help, nothing more nothing less. You're right in that it can be **adapted** into a generic question, but until that occurs it's too localised for SO. And I wouldn't agree with that definition of "quality": quality is about sufficient information to answer, politely formed question with proper spelling and grammar, with evidence that there's a real problem to be solved. Again, that has nothing to do with what is and isn't on topic and within scope here.

Comment: @Tomalak, I agree entirely that the question suffers from insufficient  information to be properly answered.  By your own definition of quality, this is clearly a quality issue rather than a localisation one as you assert elsewhere.  I also agree that low quality questions should be rejected, though I stick with Weinberg's definition, such that questions and their answers that are of insignificant probable value to others should be deleted.  IMHO, using metrics such as grammar, spelling and polite wording to measure quality (future value to others) is all wrong in the context of programming.

Comment: @Shane: Whether this question is low quality or not is not what I was talking about. All I'm saying here is that the question is too localised, and that this is not the same as a question being of low-quality, and that localised questions are bad on SO. And spelling/grammar/politeness _is_ important for keeping SO a nice, good-looking place to hang out (and is just a respectful thing to do, if nothing else). Ignoring them just because we're programmers seems... odd.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm not suggesting ignoring spelling, grammar, etc... I'm merely suggesting that by comparison to pertinent information they provide relatively little value, and hence are not a good metric with which to measure the merit of a post.  As for type of questions to be asked, the faq specifically refers to "specific programming problems" and says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"  I don't see where this question falls foul of the type of questions recommended by the faq.

Comment: @Shane: You have your opinion, and I have mine. :)

Answer (score 5):

The line that says "within this context" should direct you to the point in the code where someone is trying to allocate a GameDirector object instead of using the `sharedDirector` method.

Comment: Thank you, that was really stupid of me... in Xcode itself it was saying that the error was on that line, but in the debug console it shows that its in another file!

Answer (score 2):

The part of the error "within this context" should have a line number in it that points you to a piece of code NOT in your class definition, but somewhere you're accidentally trying to create a `GameDirector` directly rather than through the `sharedDirector` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are.

You must be trying to instantiate an object of type `GameDirector` somewhere. We could only guess at where.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create instance of GameDirector somewhere else. The snippet you posted compiles with no error.